# PHP decoding html encoded characters

Tags: php

I have problem decoding html encoded character using php, what should i do?

Below is the sample input.

```
 %D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87 %D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%87
```

Below is the sample output i want.

```
اثاره المره
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function:

```
urldecode("%D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87 %D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%87");
```